# Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I get an error, "Can't read property", if I follow the below approach. I would like to know how parsing of angular JS is done. Is it done before custom Javascript is executed or after.

```
 //Angular JS code

            myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            myApp.controller('controller', function($scope)
            {
                    $scope.student = {
                    firstName: "Mark",
                    lastName: "Smith",

                    //returns a string

                    dummyVar: (function () {
                        return "Hello";
                    }()),

                    fullName: (function() {
                        var studentObject;
                        studentObject = $scope.student;
                        return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
                    }())
                };
            });

    //Html Code

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="controller">
            First name is {{ student.firstName }}
            <br><br>
            Last name is {{ student.lastName }}
            <br><br>
            Dummy Variable is {{ student.dummyVar }}
            <br><br>
            Full Name is {{ student.fullname }}
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>**
```

Comment: This error goes away, if I write plain javascript function instead of  anonymous function fullname  and  call it from html like {{ student.fullname() }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register the function `fullName` inside the $scope object, the object itself has not been created yet. So $scope.student doesn't exist and is set as undefined when creating the object;

Use a filter or a function after the object is created or make the API returning the object concatenate the fullname.

Comment: If I write                                                                                               fullName: function() {
                        var studentObject;
                        studentObject = $scope.student;
                        return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
                    } and call it from html as {{ student.function() }} then it will give the proper output. Can you explain why this happens?